# MPDF row page break

Tags: mpdf

I have a problem in mpdf. I have 2 rows in a table. The 1st row fit in the first page, but the 2nd row is put on the next page cause it have a lot of data, but there is too much space on the first page.

I want to at least make the row, cut to occupy the remaining space on the first page. Is this possible in mpdf? If yes, how can I do that?

Comment: CAn u post some css code how u r framing the table and all. So that it will be easy to answer your question.

Comment: I used the default css in mpdf.

Comment: Same issue for me. Is this issue resolved?